# Centring vertical menu CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

My website is [Verdacci.com](http://Verdacci.com)

My question is, when viewing the website on desktop (not responsive version), I would like to center the menu vertically. So the menu is always in the center of the screen. Can somebody help me to do this? I don't want to change any code except the CSS.

Also note that if the screen size height reduces to less than 600px (i think its 600), the menu is replaced with a mini menu. I would like this functionality to remain.

I have tried quite a few things already with no luck. My CSS skill is not very high so please try to explain in as simple terms as possible? Thank you!!

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML and CSS within your question.

Comment: Just a guess, but unless you have it set up to where you know the exact width of your menu, you'll need to change the HTML or add JS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center something in CSS you can do this:

```
.yourclass {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Add this class to your menu and it should work.

Comment: How ill this work? My menu is a vertical menu, with links going downwards.